# When a function needs to be a member function

Tags: c++

I am trying to fugure out when is the best time to use member functions (static) , and when to add just an helper method in the .cpp file.

Assuming that in class MyClass I want to convert TypeA to typeB. 
This is a long process so I will add a method to handle the conversion.

The method is pure functional and has nothing to do with the state of the MyClass instance.
It gets an input and produces output without using any members (private or public) of MyClass.

Only MyClass is going to use this method.

Now I am not sure how this method needs to be defined:

1. static function in MyClass
2. static function in a dedicated class with this function.
3. Help method that is not a member of any class, only definition in the cpp file.

Comment: If it is conceptually coupled with `MyClass` only, than it should be made a private static and introduced int the `MyClass` namespace.

Comment: Whenever possible and the use of this function is restricted to `MyClass`, I'd opt for 3. (in an unnamed namespace).

Comment: A little "utility" function like this, I do #3 (in unnamed namespace as well), maybe to avoid recompiling if using as static function in header file. But it doesn't matter much between 1 and 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 3.Help method that is not a member of any class, only definition in the cpp file.

So you can change the definition of the helper method if you need, without worrying about the recompilation of the `MyClass`'s clients in the case of making it a static member function.

**EDIT:**
As @πάνταῥεῖ said, you could put the helper method in an unnamed namespace to restrict its usage within the `MyClass` cpp file (and translation units including it).

Comment: The unnamed namespace is to avoid name clashes between files. It doesn't restrict the use to only one class.

Comment: @NeilKirk Yes, if include the cpp file. This trick relies on the programming conventions partly.

Comment: I don't understand that.

Comment: @songyuanyao It restricted for use within the TU. A single TU isn't restricted to contain the definition only for one class.

Answer (score 3):

If, as you say, "Only `MyClass` is going to use this method" then it logically belongs in `MyClass` as a static member function.

Comment: Or as a local function in the only source file it is used.